# Significance of the name Annabel Lee?

Tags: poetry, name-significance, edgar-allan-poe

["Annabel Lee"](http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/edgar_allan_poe/poems/18852) is one of many pieces of writing by Edgar Allan Poe which explore the theme of a beloved woman who died young. As with other such works, most famously "The Raven", critics have speculated about who this young woman might have been based on, e.g. Poe's own wife or his mother. But I'm curious if there's any significance to be extracted from the *name* "Annabel Lee". **Do we have any clues about how or why Poe chose this name** (which might be separate from the inspiration behind the *character*)?

Comment: Is it too simplistic to assume that he simply picked a name for its rhymes and scansion?

Comment: @user14111 A justification for this name based on purely linguistic aspects of the poem (rhyme, rhythm, etc.) would be very interesting. I'm not restricting this only to answers along the lines of "her name was inspired by so-and-so in real life".

Comment: @Randal'Thor Poe had a relationship with a woman named Nancy Locke Heywood in the last few years of his life.  He referred to her as "Annie".  He developed a relationship with her around 1848 and Annabel Lee was published in 1849.  He also published a poem titled "For Annie" in dedication to Ms. Heywood.  This was also published in 1849.  Coincidence?  Maybe.  It's certainly interesting.  Not enough evidence for an answer, though.